# How can I pass a pandas data frame into a request parameter

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

I am trying to do something like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'Desktop/test.csv')

url = 'http://localhost:5000/run_model'

response = requests.post(url, data=df)
```

But I am having this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: just pass the file itself

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your endpoint you can convert your DataFrame to CSV or json like

```
df.to_json()
```

or

```
df.to_csv()
```

Comment: Ye... I guess that is impossible to pass it as a pandas dataframe, you need to convert it to a json for example